# How to Hide the Back Side of Door Once Open? Vanilla JS/CSS Door Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I have a door animation using vanilla JS with CSS for the styling. Is there a way to hid the backside of the door when it's open?
As well as making the door not clickable. (I don't have it as toggle, but you can still interact with the button.)

Basically I just want a back background and not see the backwards "1" when the door is open.

Any ideas on how to make that happen?  I imagine it's adding another div with style, but I really am not sure after goofing around with this for a while.

Cheers!

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/LYZKEvB

HTML:

```
<div>
      <div class="door-back">
        <button class="door">1</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.door-back {
  position: relative;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/e84gxikhoul21.jpg");
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.door {
  position: absolute;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.doorOpen {
  transform: perspective(1200px) translateZ(0px) translateX(0px) translateY(0px)
    rotateY(-150deg);
}

.d1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

JS

```
const doorEl = document.querySelector(".door");
doorEl.addEventListener('click', openTheDoor)

function openTheDoor() {
    doorEl.classList.add("doorOpen");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve both disable the `click` on door button and not to show the '1' after the  door is open in CSS.

```css
.doorOpen {
 ...other css
  // you just need add this property which disables click
  pointer-events: none;
  color: black;
}
```

Making the text color black will make it complete black.

If you completely want to remove the text '1' then you can do like below.

```
const doorEl = document.querySelector(".door");
doorEl.addEventListener('click', openTheDoor)

function openTheDoor() {
    doorEl.classList.add("doorOpen");
    doorEl.textContent='';
}
```

These are two ways I can think of.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel like such an idiot... I'm using innerHTML = " " for another attribute in my project to clear a modal when it's closed and didn't even this of your second way. fantastic. Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution: change the text color on transition:

```js
const doorEl = document.querySelector(".door");
doorEl.addEventListener('click', openTheDoor)

function openTheDoor() {
  doorEl.classList.toggle("doorOpen");
}
```

```css
.door-back {
  position: relative;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/e84gxikhoul21.jpg");
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.door {
  position: absolute;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out, 
    color 0s .3s linear
}

.doorOpen {
  transform: perspective(1200px) translateZ(0px) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotateY(-150deg);
  color:black;
}

.d1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="door-back">
    <button class="door">1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this https://codepen.io/dom-the-dev/pen/MWeqaJq just have a button on the opposite side that acts like the back of the door

```
<div>
  <div class="door-back">
    <button class="door front">1</button>
    <button class="door back">2</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually used something like this for a card flip animation I ddid before, but I didn't realyl think of it. The trouble is is that I'm using 25 door elements, so I would need to make 25 more elements if I wanted to do it this. 
But I may actually use this! I appreciate the response!